# How should I list a custom degree on my resume? (post-Soviet Specialist degree)

Tags: resume, degree

The degree I have is a Specialist degree, it's a specific kind of degree that takes 5 years to obtain and is common in post-Soviet countries. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialist_degree

This degree is evaluated by some credentials evaluation organizations as (Bachelor's degree + Master's degree). See https://www.wes.org/advisor-blog/credential-evaluations-russian-students/

What would be the best way to list this degree on my resume to not confuse the recruiters in English-speaking countries and to let them know that I basically have a Master's degree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a comparison in parenthesis:

> University of X, Specialist degree in Y (comparable to Master's degree)

Comment: "Comparable" leaves some ambiguity. Should I maybe list it like: `Specialist degree (equivalent to M.S.)`
?

Comment: Sure! You are not lying, you are helping the reader.

Comment: Should I add a reference to a website of a particular evaluation organization where the equivalency is explained as a proof? So they could double-check if in doubt.

Comment: @Konrad I'd say probably not. You can't click on a link when the resume's printed out, after all, and most resumes will be read and then either passed forward to the next step in the process or thrown in the garbage after 30 seconds.